# How to set background to a solid color programmatically in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome

I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background primary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background secondary-color '#000000'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background color-shading-type 'solid'
```

However, my background is still the default heisenbug picture.

What setting do I have to change to use my color instead of the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `picture-uri` value to an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Should set picture-options to "none":

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options 'none'
```

Otherwise, when I only do https://stackoverflow.com/a/20594882/488373 (picture-uri "") then I can see error logs from GNOME trying to load an image with an incomplete/missing filename over and over and over